# How can I write a logic for this question in PowerBI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[image]

For each id, I have a count of images column and check column

and my conditions are :

1)a count of images should be 8

2)In the check column for all 8 images, it should be **valid** then the result is  **No anamoly**.

if I have anyone of stint is invalid/blank the result is **anamoly found**

please provide a condition/logic by writing a DAX query in powerbi. I need result as a measure in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Measure = if(

CALCULATE(
COUNT(Table1[check]),
FILTER(Table1,
[check]="valid")
)=8,
"No anamoly","anamoly found "
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform your a bit. In transform query you will need to fill down the ID field, this is important because you will use it in creating a table where you will drag the measure into.

The measure:

```
measure _x = calculate(countrows(Table[1]), filter(Table[Check] = "valid")))
```

Then you can write a helper measure:

```
mearsure _y = if(measure _y = 8 , "No Anomaly", "Anomaly found")
```